# Getting wrong alert while checking whether the posting date is greater than current date in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have an html input (input type is text) field with date picker. Picking the date  from datepicker in "mm-dd-yyyy" format (09-02-2015 for today). When I am checking whether the input date is greater than current date, in some cases I am getting wrong alert. 
When I am posting date as 09-03-2015(tomorrows date - sep-03-2015), getting alert that 09-03-2015 is a lower date than 09-02-2015. For 09-10-2015(Sep-10-2015)  I am getting proper alert 09-10-2015 is a post date than 09-02-2015. 
Please support and advice how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance. 
Here is the my Code.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="newlog" name="newlog" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">SR Date (mm/dd/yyyy)</label>
                      <div class="col-lg-4">
                          <input id='date' name="date" type="text" class="form-control default-date-picker" value="">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="finish btn btn-success" value="Save"/>
              </form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $currentdate = date('m-d-Y');
        $mydate = $_POST["date"];
        $newDate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($mydate));

        if ($newDate > $currentdate) {
            echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
function redir()
{
alert(' " . $newDate . " is a post date than " . $currentdate . "  ');
window.location.assign('test.php');
}
</script>
<body onload='redir();'></body>";
        } else {
            echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
function redir()
{
alert(' " . $mydate . " is a lower date date than " . $currentdate . "');
window.location.assign('test.php');
}
</script>
<body onload='redir();'></body>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing `$newDate` to make sure `strtotime()` is handling it the way you expect?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang No, the $newdate is showing in dd-mm-yyyy format for some cases (eg: 10-09-2015 for sep - 10 - 2015 and 09-03-2015 for sep - 3 - 2015) in the alert also.

Comment: Wait-- so no, you haven't tried it (?) or no, it's not rendering as expected?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang it is not giving the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

strtotime() assumes an English date format by default. I suggest you use datetime.createfromformat as that understands different date formatting.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

So, in your case, you might say:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('m-j-Y', '09-03-2015');
```